# Dynamically adding Content to a table Cell

Tags: javascript, html

Hi My table is as follows, what i want to do is get the current value from the cell and increase by one and then print it back in the same cell, Everything is illustrated below.

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%">No</th>
                <th width="10%">Model No</th>
                <th width="15%">Model/Make</th>
                <th width="20%">Price</th>
                <th width="20%">Available Quantity</th>
                <th width="20%">Add to or Remove from Cart</th>
                <th width="10%">No of Items</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>001</td>
                <td>SONY</td>
                <td>5000</td>
                <td>10 Units</td>               
                <td align="center">
                <input type="image" src="images/add.png" name="add" id="add" onclick="add();"/>
                </td>
                <td id="The_Dynamic_Cell">0</td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The Java Script

```
function add(){

Get the current Content of the cell (id="The_Dynamic_Cell") and increase the value by 1 (content++) and re populate the cell with new value. 

}
```

How can I achieve the above? Thanks in advance

Comment: NO Jquery, I cant use any external Libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion, don't bind events within the DOM element. Here's a simple way to bind a click event. Notice that the jsfiddle option `No Wrap - in body` - Basically this means that you have a `script` tag at the end (inside) your `body` tag to make sure the elements have rendered in the DOM by the time you run this code:

```
var addButton = document.querySelector("#add");
var cell = document.querySelector("#The_Dynamic_Cell");

addButton.onclick = function add(e){
    cell.innerText =  parseInt(cell.innerText, 10) + 1; 
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/4nmWE/1/)

If you must adapt this to work with your above example (binding on the element), then you can try the following:

```
var cell = document.querySelector("#The_Dynamic_Cell");

function add(e){
    cell.innerText =  parseInt(cell.innerText, 10) + 1; 
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/4nmWE/3/)

You can read more events [here](https://github.com/ChaseWest/Blog/blob/master/May-2014/Events.md) or [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

Comment: @mohamedrias - Thanks, just want to make sure the OP knows that binding the event in JS rather than within the element is best. Separation of concerns :D

Comment: I would suggest using document.getElementById() as the user just wants to use ID. querySelector is a good option as it uses CSS selectors. But it's not supported in older browsers.

Comment: @mohamedrias - Yeah, there are a few things here that would need to be changed for a robust example, but for a simple example it'll do :D

Comment: @user2627018 - I'm glad you found it helpful =)

Answer (score 1):

```
   function add() {
     var tdEle = document.getElementById("The_Dynamic_Cell");
     tdEle.innerText = parseInt(tdEle.innerText, 10) +1;
   }
```

This will get the cell with ID `The_Dynamic_Cell` and will increment its value by 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, wish I could accept both as answers. This too works fine..:)